# fontawesome not showing when using local asset

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I saved the contents of fontawesome cdn contents info a local assets at `mysite.com/assets/css/font-awesome-5.15.3.min.css` but when I want to use the `fa-file-upload` icon in my web page, it shows a broken image icon instead. what am I doing wrong? what's the solution? any help is appreciated.

[image: broken icon image]

I wanted to try using a cdn instead but the `https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome` returns an empty page and I couldn't find any other cdns for fontawesome. the instructions for cdn in the fontawesome official website is forcing me to use the Kit instead, and for that I have to sign up and login. seems to much of a hassle. what's wrong with the old simple fontawesome? where has it gone to?

Answer (score 0):

To use the Font Awesome V5 [Upload](https://fontawesome.com/v5/icons/upload?f=classic&s=solid) icon, you need to use the following classes `fas fa-upload` according to the documentation.

You can find Font Awesome on cdnjs.com [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-upload" style="font-size:24px"></i>
```